# createFromResources() in ArrayAdapter cannot be applied to spinner

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-spinner

Im having trouble when creating an ArrayAdapter on my spinner. i don't know how to explain to you guys but people say a picture speaks 1000 words. so i provide a picture of my problem. please help me i really dont know what to do know.

[image: this is my error]

this is my class

```
public class SettingFragment extends Fragment{

private View rootView;
Spinner spinner;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;

public SettingFragment(){
    //required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_setting, container, false);

    spinner = (Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.select_font_size, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    return rootView;
}
```

}

this is my string.xml

```
<string-array name="select_font_size">
    <item>Small</item>
    <item>Default</item>
    <item>Large</item>
    <item>Larger</item>
</string-array>
```

and this is my xml code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to move the creation of the adapter inside the `onActivityCreated` callback when you know for sure that by calling `getActivity()` you will get a not null instance of the activity:

```
public class SettingFragment extends Fragment{

private View rootView;
Spinner spinner;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;

public SettingFragment(){
    //required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_setting, container, false);
    spinner = (Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.select_font_size, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Application context, or context of the activity instantiating the fragment.

```
adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(), R.array.select_font_size, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

OR

```
adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(YOUR_ACTIVITY_CONTEXT_TO_BE_PASSED_INTO_FRAGMENT, R.array.select_font_size, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```